# How to list all available LookAndFeel themes?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

How to list all available LookAndFeel themes?
I want to show then in a JComboBox for the user to select.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really simple:

```
public static UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] getInstalledLookAndFeels()
```

by the way check `UIManager` documentation [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html)

Comment: By your method, one item in that list could represent the `Metal` look and feel class. Metal has two themes, `"DefaultMetal"` & `"Ocean"`, some other look and feels might also do this. Your question does not answer the original question which explicitly says `How to list all available LookAndFeel themes`

Answer (score 6):

```
UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] lafInfo = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
```