# Java GUI Theme Looks Like In Design

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I want to change GUI application to be like in design (theme).

This is how it looks when I launch program
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOrux.jpg)

And this is how it looks in design
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANtX0.jpg)

For example, this combobox in design is much prettier than in actual program.

Comment: You may want to test with different _Look and Feel_ : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655513/how-to-list-all-available-lookandfeel-themes

Comment: I found solution. Thanks!

Comment: I hope your solution is based around `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` rather than trying to set it to Windows Look and Feel..

Comment: Yes, exactly that :)